# How to show error message every time when validation fails on an icefaces component?

Tags: jsf, message, icefaces, validation, textinput

I'm facing some validation/message problem with ICEFaces. I have a page with some input fields, validators, and a message bar with an `<ice:messages />` tag. If the user fails to properly complete an input field a validation error occurs, and an error message shown in the message bar. So far, so good.
But if the user types an incorrect value for the second time too, no new error message shown.
I would like to know how to change this behaviour. I need an error message every time the user fails to set a proper value, not just for the first time.
How can I do that?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're not receiving an exception after printing the error message?